# gitosis crontab using public/private key pairs

Tags: debian, cron, git

I have a debian server (2.6.18-6-686, etch) set up with gitosis (0.2+20080825-2) installed.  Everything works just fine, but my problem is that when I clone and pull any repository it requests the password of my private key and I am wondering if there is anyway to instead request the password for the key it would just use the private/public key pair to authenticate and not require a password.

Right now this is what happens

```
$ git pull
Enter passphrase for key '/home/stmpy/.ssh/id_rsa':
```

once I put the password in then the pull works, but I don't want to have to input my password.  I am trying to create a crontab that would pull changes and update a website I work on every night, but with it requesting the password it doesn't appear to work.

I've looked up tutorials about creating cron jobs with gitosis and no one appears to be doing anything about the password, which is why I think I have something configured wrong.  I have not done any custom editing to gitosis or sshd.  So both servers are running default settings.

Any help would be great, and sorry if this is a duplicate, I looked around for an hour or so and couldn't find an answer to this.  Thanks again!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Re-generated the key pair with **no** passphrase, it will not ask anymore.